# Eloquent - Load child relationship depending on data of parent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to select data from my database model together with some relations. Here is an example:

```
House::with(
    'doors'
    'windows',
    'windows.childA',
    'windows.childB',
    'windows.childC',
    'stairs'
    )
    ->get();
```

But now I only want to select childC if the id of the window is within a array of numbers. But how is this possible? When I try this:

```
 House::with(
    'doors'
    'windows',
    'windows.childA',
    'windows.childB',
    'windows.childC' => function($q) {
        $q->whereIn('windows.id', [1,6,3,7]);
    },
    'stairs'
    )
    ->get();
```

I get an error "Column not found". Also, using the database table name instead of `windows` doesn't work, too. What can I try next?

### Edit

Window inside House model

```
public function windows()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Window', 'house_id', 'id');
}
```

Relations inside Window model

```
public function childA()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ChildA', 'window_id', 'id');
}

public function childC()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ChildC', 'window_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: could you please share the relationship code?

Comment: i think you should ditch the preconception that `with()` will result in sql `join`, try to dump your query using `toSql()` or enable laravel db query log to see the entire query. if you need to do a complex join, `QueryBuilder` often times the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```php
 House::with(
    'doors'
    'windows',
    'windows.childA',
    'windows.childB',
    'windows.childC' => function($q) {
        $q->whereIn('window_id', [1,6,3,7]);
    },
    'stairs'
    )
    ->get();
```